# Flash Builder / Internet Explorer and disabled add-ons

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, flash

I have been experiencing a very annoying problem in Windows 7x64. Every once in a while when I start debugging a project from the Flash Builder (4.0 now, 4.6 before), all IE add-ons are disabled and there is no possibility of enabling them. This includes Flash, so my project does not start. This occurs with IE 8, 9, and 10. with McAfee OAS.

Sometimes restoring default security settings in IE helps, sometimes it doesn't. If it doesn't, I restart my computer which... sometimes helps, sometimes doesn't.

If it doesn't I am forced to reinstall Flash and after that all of the add-ons (including Flash) are enabled again... until next time.

I have been looking for solutions on the Internet, but haven't found anything related to the topic.